# python: How can I use __import__ to import specific name in a module?

Tags: python

I tried to use the keyword argument fromlist to emulate 'from urllib import urlopen'.What's the correct way to do this? Hope for your help.

```
    mymodule = __import__('urllib',fromlist=['urlopen'])
    >>> urlopen('http://www.google.com')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'urlopen' is not defined
```